# Vbscript help-read a text file line by line and populate contents of each line in an excel and search and count for a repeating string

Tags: vbscript

I want to read a text file line by line (using readline function instead of readall) for searching a repeating string (like "hi, how are you buddy?") in the text file. The user is providing the string and the text file path as inputs.I want the following outputs to populate in an output excel: 
1. test data (the string you are searching for in the text file and that is present multiple times)
2.contents each line should be populated in a column 
3. if the test data is found in any of the lines, result in "Y" else "N"  in another column of the output excel file
4.line index (means, for first line it would be 1, and so on).

I have searched on net and make my code accordingly but i am unable to loop the readline functionality through the entire text file and i cant generate the contents of each line in the result output excel.I will be highly obliged if you kindly help me out in the code.

```
Sub main()


'creating new excel file in date-time format for gathering output

Dim a
a = Now
Dim strFileName

a = Replace(a, "/", "_")
a = Replace(a, ":", "_")
a = Replace(a, " ", "_")

strFileName = "search output_" & a & ".xls"

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
'objExcel.Visible = True
Set objWorkBook = objExcel.Workbooks.Add()
Set Objsheet = objWorkBook.Sheets(1)
Row = 4
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 2) = "Test data"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 4) = "Total row count"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 6) = "Each row Index"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 8) = "Row content"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 10) = "Test data found ?" & vbNewLine & "Y" & "or" & "N"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 12) = "Count of test data in the row"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 14) = "Reported by"




Dim Str_input, strTextFile                                           'declaring variables

Str_input = Trim(TextBox_String.Text)                                'user providing input search string

strTextFile = TextBox_Path.Text                                      'User providing text file path

Const ForReading = 1


'contents = ObjFile.readall
'contents = ObjFile.ReadLine

'i = 0
'linesArray = Split(contents, Chr(10))
'For Each lineStr In linesArray
'If InStr(lineStr, Str_input) Then
      'i = i + 1
   'End If
'Next

'ObjFile.Close

Set ObjFso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
Set ObjFile = ObjFso.OpenTextFile(strTextFile, ForReading)
Content = ObjFile.Readall
Do While Not ObjFile.AtEndOfStream
contents = ObjFile.ReadLine
MsgBox "the output" & Content
Loop

'Set fso = CreateObject("Scripting.FileSystemObject")
'Set listFile = fso.OpenTextFile(aniLines).Readall
'Do While Not listFile.AtEndOfStream
    'fName = listFile.ReadLine()
    'WScript.Echo fName
    'Loop
'Next

Row = 6

Objsheet.Cells(Row, 2) = Str_input
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 4) = ObjFile.Line - 1                                     'No of rows in total
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 6) = " Each row index"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 8) = "Row content"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 10) = "Test data found ?" & "Y" & "or" & "N"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 12) = "Count of test data in the row"
Objsheet.Cells(Row, 14) = "Alex Rider"

objWorkBook.SaveAs "D:\" & strFileName                                           'saving the output excel

Set objExcel = Nothing: Set objBook = Nothing: Set Objsheet = Nothing

End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

After

```
Content = ObjFile.Readall
```

the end of the file/stream is reached, so that the

```
Do While Not ObjFile.AtEndOfStream
```

loop will not be entered.